# How do you use authentication with gmail for a PHP contact form?

Tags: php, forms, smtp, gmail, smtp-auth

This is the code that i have working; however i want to incorporate a way to have an smtp authentication using my gmail account but I can't figure it out...help?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "jfk003@lvc.edu";
    $email_subject = "Website Inquire";


    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = "/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/";
  if (preg_match($email_exp, $email_from)) {
    echo "Email address is valid.";
  }
  else 

    {
        echo "Email address is <u>not</u> valid.";
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[a-zA-Z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

} 

?>
```

Comment: I was about to say that I thought this code contains every single PHP email anti-pattern ever conceived of, but you're missing header injection.  Darn.  It's also [a duplicate of at least a *few* of the **200** questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%2Bgmail+%2Bsmtp) about sending mail from PHP via Gmail's SMTP servers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a modern PHP mailing library, like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) that supports SMTP authentication.

Check out [Google's instructions on which servers to use](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287) and SwiftMailer's docs on [sending mail to a SSL/TLS SMTP server](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-encryption) and [sending mail with a username/password combo](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/smtp-authentication).

While updating your code to use SwiftMailer, you should ditch that *abomination* of an email validation regex, it excludes numerous completely valid local parts and domains.  The sanity straight-jacket imposed by [building the message using method calls](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref) is going to take care of most of the other potential problems in your code, like that bizarre `clean_string` function -- you won't need it (and I'm not sure what you think it does here, but it doesn't really, uh, make the string any safer).

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with this swiftmailer stuff.  I downloaded but I don't really know much about php or anything related to it.  I just know css and html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHPMailer http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/, here is how you send email using GMail, but HTML&CSS won't help you much here.

```
function email($to, $subject, $body){
    require_once("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->Username = "name@example";
    $mail->Password = "123456";

    $mail->SetFrom("name@example.com", "Name Example");

    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Send();
    unset($mail);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using gmail; google change there authentication methods, I was able to successfully authenticate following this step first:
[Video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMabEyrtPRg&t=2m13s) this is for the 2 step process to allow external application

you will need to generate an  application password.

then use that password for your PHP application.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a complete working example.    
<?php
    // this is for troubleshooting errors 
    // set the 1 to 0 to turn off (must set to 0 when in production mode or when you run this live 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?><?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email_to       = $_POST['email'];
        $email_subject  = "E-mail from website visitor.";

        // try adding a useful/relevent message to errors output to users
        function died($error) {
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted:\n\t ";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
            die();
        }

        // validation expected data exists
        // since all post are submit, check if they are empty or equal to an empty string
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
            if($_POST['email'] == "" || $_POST['first_name'] == "" || $_POST['last_name'] == "" || $_POST['telephone'] == "" || $_POST['comments'] == ""){
                died('Please fill out the entire form');
            }
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $last_name  = $_POST['last_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $telephone  = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
        $comments   = $_POST['comments']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from))
            $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name))
            $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name))
            $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
        if(strlen($comments) < 2)
            $error_message .= 'The Message you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
        if(strlen($error_message) > 0)
            died($error_message);
        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
            $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
            return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }
        $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

        // create email headers
        // changed up your email a bit
        $headers = "From: $email_from\n";
        $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
        header('Location: http://www.cnn.com');
        exit();
    }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
    Firstname:<br>
    <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
    Lastname:<br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Phone Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="telephone"><br>
    Comments:<br>
    <input type="textarea" name="comments"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You can change the header to relocate the user to your login script or homepage instead of cnn.